# Looping through SqlDataReader returns same row twice

Tags: vb.net, sqldatareader

I'm making a VB.NET (4.6) Windows form application that collects info on our servers and allows us to do reports on it. It's coming together nicely but I've run into an issue I can't figure out. One part of the project is a service that queries the info on available Windows updates from WSUS and then stores them in an SQL database - that part works fine. I'm now trying to present this data in a DataGridView using an SqlDataReader to query the info from the database and fill up a DataTable with the response. The problem is that when I use the reader, it puts the same record in the DataTable twice. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I'm sure it's something super simple. Perhaps one of you folks can spot the problem?

Note: Earlier in the application, the updateid's are stored as unique strings in a list called dbupdateidlist, the results are stored in a DataTable called dbupTable, and the datagridview I'm trying to update is called UpdateDeetsView.

```
Public Sub getUpdateDetails()

    For Each str As String In dbupdateidlist
        Dim commGetUpdateDetails As String = "select upTableId, title, classification, description, " +
        "releasedate, severity, articlenumber, url from updatedetails where updateid = '" + str + "'"
        Using connObj As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Using cmdObj As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(commGetUpdateDetails, connObj)
                connObj.Open()
                Using readerObj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdObj.ExecuteReader
                    While readerObj.Read

                        dbuptabid = readerObj("uptableid")
                        dbuptitle = readerObj("title")
                        dbupclass = readerObj("classification")
                        dbupdesc = readerObj("description")
                        dbupreleasedate = readerObj("releasedate")
                        dbupseverity = readerObj("severity")
                        dbuparticlenumber = readerObj("articlenumber")
                        dbupurl = readerObj("url")

                        row = dbupTable.NewRow()
                        row("uptableid") = dbuptabid
                        row("title") = dbuptitle
                        row("classification") = dbupclass
                        row("description") = dbupdesc
                        row("releasedate") = dbupreleasedate
                        row("severity") = dbupseverity
                        row("articlenumber") = dbuparticlenumber
                        row("url") = dbupurl
                        dbupTable.Rows.Add(row)
                    End While

                End Using
                connObj.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
    UpdateDeetsView.DataSource = dbupTable
End Sub
```

Forgive the likely terrible code, I'm an SA not a dev...

Comment: There is no need to move the rows one by one to a datatable.  `dbupTable.Load(readerObj.ExecuteReader)` will fill the table for you.  If you have that table elsewhere, you could just use a DataView of it.  But by all means, turn on Option Strict

Comment: Even if just an SA, always use parameters to avoid SQL Injection and formatting issues.

Comment: Does `dbupdateidlist` contain duplicated values?

Comment: This is not a sql-server question, please use tags properly.

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the tip! But, I replaced the entire While loop with dbupTable.Load(cmdObj.ExecuteReader) and it still shows two results. What would Option Strict do for me?

Comment: Make sure there is not duplicate data in the db.  An easy way to make that reusable would be to remove the WHERE clause and just apply a filter `Id In (...)`

Comment: @AndrewMorton no the items in that list are unique. I also tried it by providing the updateid directly as a variable, as opposed to using the list, and it had the same behavior.

Comment: This should be a function that returns data.  It's hard to help you because we don't know how many times you are calling this procedure.  It isn't clearing the existing data.  We don't know what your dbupdateidlist contains, etc, etc.

Comment: @LarsTech I appreciate the feedback. I have one table that has update events, and another table that has the updates that are included in that event. The sub I posted is run once based on the eventid from the first table and then fills the second table with the update details pertaining to that event. I was hoping this would be something really obvious that someone smarter than me would see easily, but it seems like it might be something different

Comment: Fill the table with all the rows; Use String.Join to convert dbupdateidlist into a SQL compatible list `'123', 'ABC', '1XY'`.  Use that as a row filter `Id IN (the joined list)` .  If the ID filter changes, just rebuild the list of ids

Comment: Thanks, @Plutonix, for the advice. I'll be perfectly honest, I barely understand it haha - I have a VERY basic understanding of this code stuffs. I think you're saying get the data from the database into a table and filter it from there, independent of the database?

Comment: Not only is there no need to loop through the reader to load a datatable, there's no need to use a datatable to the datagridview. You can just say: `UpdateDeetsView.DataSource = cmdObj.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Plutonix, I went with Joels answer and it worked but I'm sure this would as well and I really appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Public Sub getUpdateDetails()
    Dim sql As String = _    
        "SELECT DISTINCT upTableId, title, classification, description, releasedate, " & _
            " severity, articlenumber, url " & _
       " FROM updatedetails " & _ 
       " WHERE updateid = @updateID"

    Using cn  As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString), _
          cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@updateID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int32.Parse(dbupdateidlist.First())
        cn.Open()
        UpdateDeetsView.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Note the use of DISTINCT and the complete lack of any explicit loops whatsoever.

Also note that I'm only looking at one entry in `dbupdateidlist`. The real source of your old bug may have been to have the the ID in that list twice.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This worked and suddenly only getting one row.

Comment: @user1806800  Contradicts your statement  "I've run it in SMSS and I get the one result"

Comment: @Paparazzi I think the original problem was the ID value was in the `dbupdateidlist` list twice. Thus it was running the sql statement twice without clearing the datatable in between.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I asked the OP to test in SSMS and OP commented to me 1 row was returned

Comment: @Paparazzi Exactly. Notice this line from the question: `For Each str As String In dbupdateidlist`. There were two values in `dbupdateidlist`. So each row is returned by the query once, but the query ran twice. So the real fix in my answer is either the use of `.First()` to only get one entry, or assigning directly to the Datasource, which would clear items from any previous run.

Comment: What?  If the query was returning one this distinct would not have changed anything. For the third time:  I asked the OP to run the query in SSMS and was told by OP the query returned one row.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** way readerObj.Read is failing to move to the next record

get the output of this and run it is SSMS

```
"select upTableId, title, classification, description, " +  
"releasedate, severity, articlenumber, url from updatedetails where updateid = '" + str + "'"
```

Comment: You may have misunderstood my question, it's returning two rows when only one exists. I've run it in SMSS and I get the one result, but if it's run by the reader I get the same row twice in the DataGridView.

Comment: Not buying that.  Run it in debug and I will bet you only see one loop if 1 row is return.

Comment: @user1806800 That image is NOT proof that loop returned two rows.  Trace it in debug mode and no way it loops twice if query returns one row.   Knock, knock - if you call that twice than that is the results you would get.

Comment: Knock, knock - I realize it's being called twice, that's why i'm asking if anyone sees a reason why that would be happening. Telling me I'm doing something wrong isn't an answer.

Comment: @user1806800 I'd doublecheck the assumption that only one row exists

Comment: Knock, knock.  You state "looping through through SqlDataReader returns the same row twice".  That is false.  The *loop* is not return the same row twice.    If it is being called twice then you are calling it twice.  The answer is yes you are doing something wrong - that loop is doing exactly was it is supposed to do.

Comment: Then what is? Again you're just saying I'm doing something wrong not offering any advice or possible solutions. Obviously, I came here knowing I'm doing something wrong. If I'm asking the question incorrectly the suggest an alternative or don't answer, this is just wasting our time.

Comment: You came here asserting the loop is running twice and that is false.  If you are calling is twice then stop calling it twice  - only you can fix that.  If you don't get that is the answer then we cannot help you.  If you cannot trace a call to a method then we cannot help you.